# Play button over responsive image using css

Tags: css, html, flexbox

I'm trying to display play button over responsive image. Button have 96x96px and need to be at center of image.

I tried many methods but always is bad. I read something about flex design, maybe it's simple to do in flex?

I need really simple method because there will be 5 to 10 elements.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 7):

If you give the image a parent element, you can make the overlay a background image of the parent and position it in the center of the parent.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
  background: url('https://img.clipartfest.com/d0227ce70c0b9f371e7a7a018729143e_thumbs-up-smiley-face-big-thumbs-up-clipart_2891-2674.jpeg');
  background-size: cover;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
</div>
```

And here is the same technique but with the overlay as an `img` in the parent.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  width: 96px;
  height: 96px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png">
  <img src="https://img.clipartfest.com/d0227ce70c0b9f371e7a7a018729143e_thumbs-up-smiley-face-big-thumbs-up-clipart_2891-2674.jpeg" class="thumb">
</div>
```

Comment: Really best! Thank you very much my friend! :)

Answer (score 4):

Put your image into a relative container, and your play button as absolute. Somethinkg like this:

```
<div class="videoContainer">
   <img src="link_to_your_image" alt="">
   <img src="link_to_play_button" alt="play" class="playBtn">
</div>
```

and the css:

```
.videoContainer {
    position: relative;
}
.playBtn {
    position: absolute;
    width: 96px;
    height: 96px;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin-left: -48px; /*half of the width */
    margin-top: -48px; /*half of the height */
}
```

Comment: It's also great if you can provide a fiddle link or snippet link along with it in live state..!